# Bubble chart using d3.geo.mercator

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, geo, bubble-chart

I am a total D3.js n00b, so I apologize if this ends up having a super easy solution that I'm completely missing. Anyway, I'm trying to create a Bubble Chart on a world map. It'll be similar to the [Symbol Maps](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/examples/symbol-map) but using d3.geo.mercator instead of d3.geo.albersUsa. I am using the world-countries.json file and created my own world-country-centroids.json file. Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Countries of the World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../d3.v2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

svg {
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
}

#countries path, #country-centroids circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#country-centroids circle {
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: .8;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

// The radius scale for the centroids
var r = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, 1e6])
    .range([0, 10]);

// World Map Projection
var xy = d3.geo.mercator(),
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(xy);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.append("g").attr("id", "countries");
svg.append("g").attr("id", "country-centroids");

d3.json("../data/world-countries.json", function(collection) {
  svg.select("#countries")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(collection.features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(xy));
});

d3.json("../data/world-country-centroids.json", function(collection) {
  svg.select("#country-centroids")
    .selectAll("circle")
      .data(collection.features
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.properties.population - a.properties.population; }))
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xy(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
      .attr("r", 0)
    .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 50; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return r(d.properties.population); });
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's your question? what's wrong? do you get errors?

Comment: You should open the console and check what errors are outputted

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `width` and `height` attributes on the SVG element for it to be visible. Unfortunately, these attributes cannot be set via style properties because they define SVG's coordinate system in addition to the displayed size of the SVG element.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") 
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);
```

You can use style properties *in addition* to attributes if you want to rescale the SVG element (i.e., display it at a different size than its native size), but you still need to set attributes.